# Using copyrighted code

Tags: copy-paste

What is the guideline on creating a program or part of a program based on a non-free code, for example from codes [Microsoft's sample code for .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb400848%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or code found in someone's blog? The codes are there to help a programmer's work right? If one feels that part of such code is helpful in his work, does he have to reimplement them from scratch, or is it okay to copy and paste some codes? What is the limit?

Comment: The reflexive Stack Overflow answer for this type of question is "don't trust any answers for this question on SO, go ask a lawyer." That's pretty safe advice, in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the general advice of "go ask a lawyer," here are some other thoughts.

I am not a lawyer, but I am responsible, as a senior product line manager, for making the decision of when to discuss something with a lawyer.

- If you work at a company that has staff lawyers, then it is always a fine idea to go talk to them. Usually you'll want to discuss with your manager first. If you're in a product development group then you should also talk with your product manager.
- Generally speaking, there is no such thing as public domain code. Rather, every bit of code should have an license.

**Re: can I use Microsoft sample code?** Yes, as their web page says: `The .NET Framework documentation includes code examples that you can copy directly from topics and paste into your own projects.` -- Quoted from their web page that you referenced in your original question.

Added: The one liner from the MS site is a summary of their license. The actual license is longer and refuses responsibility for what the code may or may not do, suitability, etc etc. But the one line summary, especially for sample code, is clear enough.

**Re: can I use code samples from blogs** Yes and no. Blogs **should** include a license for their software postings. Some do, many do not. If they don't, consider writing to the blogger and asking something like `Which license covers your software examples from your blog? The BSD license (example from Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html) or similar?`

The reason you'd suggest that the blogger consider the BSD license is that it is very open. But, for example, the blogger could come back and say, "My examples are licensed under GPL 3."

In that case, you'd be bound by GPL 3 if you use the blogger's code.

**Added: Can I use software examples from StackOverflow?** Per the above, you should look for a software license from the blogger. And guess what? There is one for Stack Overflow. See the [Legal](https://stackoverflow.com/legal) link at the bottom of each SO page. On the Legal page, see section 3, "Subscriber content." That section gives you the license for all code samples on SO.

**Conclusion** If you want to be living within the licenses from the sw writers, then you need to know what those licenses are. If you don't know, then you run the risk of not actually having the right to use/re-license the software.

A different question, is "must I always have a proper license for software that I'm using?" The answer to that question depends on many things. The simple answer, especially if you work for any government, public or private institution is "yes." And, of course, as a proper member of society, you should also only use licensed software, for the obvious reasons.

Suppose, for instance, you see some sample code on a blog. The code is very useful to you. You want to use it. But there is no license for the code on the blog. You write the blogger, but get no reply. Can you use it? You could, but there is a risk (probably small), that the software's owner (the blogger) could decide to sue you. So then the real question is, should I assume the business risk? That's a business decision, not a technical decision. A reasonable business decision might then be, "Yes, let's use the software and take the risk of a problem."

**Added: Microsoft Public license--** Microsoft (MS) licenses its sample code via its "Microsoft Public License." Also known as the Ms-PL. The [license](http://www.microsoft.com/opensource/licenses.mspx). Example of a [.Net sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ADUtil/Project/License.aspx) referring to the Ms-PL. Another [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Project/License.aspx) of Microsoft sample code.

Comment: thanks for the answer! by the way where did you find the longer license that "is longer and refuses responsibility etc etc"?

Comment: @Louis -- the longer license for Microsoft code samples is their "Public License." I added info about it to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt copying somebody's "Hello World" or "How to connect to a database" code would be much of a copyright issue, and example code usually gives the basics. The issue here is that there are only so many ways to do something in a programming language, as long as you're not directly copying significant portions of code you should be fine.

Comment: Careful there....what is "significant portions" of code can be a long, drawn-out battle. On the other hand, if you're an individual, then you're usually not worthy of being sued. But if you are a corporation, and you use (or better, re-sell), someone's sw without a license, you might find yourself on the receiving end of a cease-and-desist letter. At that point, you'd need to make a license agreement while you're under the gun. That's no fun at all. Costly, too.

Comment: If somebody openly posts their source-code online they cannot reasonably expect it not to be used. This would greatly weaken their case. Often when looking at source-code the people who decide what is and is not infringement are not developers, the source has to be a close-enough copy of the original. This decision will change from instance to instance because there are inconsistencies in the interpretation of the law, each judge decides what the law is intended to do based on prior case-law.

Comment: Here's a counter-example: Wordpress includes some nifty code. All of it is posted on-line -- http://core.svn.wordpress.org/ But if you use any of it in your software project, ALL OF YOUR PROJECT is now affected by the Wordpress license, GPL v2. Many commercial companies might not want to have that happen to their product software.

Comment: But that's clearly licensed under GPL, one of many licences that require you to share derivative code under the same (or similar) licence, but if the code is unlicensed and there is no claim to copyright it is fair to assume it to be in the public domain.

Comment: "and there is no claim to copyright it is fair to assume it to be in the public domain" - this is completely untrue. In almost all countries copyright will expire many, many years after death of the author (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries'_copyright_lengths). Without explicit license code is fully copyrighted.

Comment: The terms (or length) of the copyright is irrelevant to the question of if an unlabeled work is protected by copyright or not, [Under US copyright law a copyright notice must be used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_notice#Technical_requirements), this may differ internationally since the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) suggests works are copyrighted once "fixed" regardless of the use of a copyright notice.